# pytest cannot import custom modules

Tags: python, pytest, importerror

I have this project structure:

```
app_root
--configs
--rest
--taf_pytest
  --core
    --authentication
    --client
    --config
    __init__.py
  --test_data
  --tests
    --test_1
    --test_2
    __init__.py
  --utils
    --routes
    __init__.py
  __init__.py
--__init__.py
```

When I run pytest, the following import error occurs:

```
python -m pytest .\taf_pytest\tests\

taf_pytest\conftest.py:11: in <module>
    from taf_pytest.core import Client
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'taf_pytest.core' (C:\my_path\app_root\taf_pytest\core\__init__.py)
```

App added to `PYTHONPATH` also tried to delete `__init__.py` from tests directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've solver my problem. It was the wrong structure.

Comment: Would be nice to describe what exact changes were necessary to fix the problem, might help others in the future.